# error when generating Apk file in react native

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I got the below error when i tried to build a apk fron react-native using this command `./gradlew assembleRelease`

D:\tmp\taamapp\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\release\drawable-hdpi\node_modules_reactnavigationstack_src_views_assets_backicon.png: error: uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file..
error: failed parsing overlays.

Answer (score 0):

There's another option you can try in `gradle.properties` which is `org.gradle.configureondemand=true`. So use that instead of `android.enableAapt2=false`.

- and removed all drawable* folders

`rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*`

- use the following command to bundle assets:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/`

Run `./gradlew clean` after.

hope it will help you :)